# closing ssh ControlPath

Tags: security, ssh, socket, cleanup

I found the instructions on [kerneltrap's mail archive: "scp batch mode?"](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/openbsd-misc/2007/8/16/153365) to be insightful an useful, however when I issue the command to close the connection

```
# Bring the connection down.
ssh -S /tmp/ssh_socket -O exit dummy
```

my ssh complains that it does not support the `-O` (that is upper case o) option.

My question is: Is it sufficient to delete the `/tmp/ssh_socket`, to properly close the connection, or am I missing some important step here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rm` is sufficient, though you can kill the control process as well with a `fuser -k /tmp/ssh_socket`.